# Formatting horizontal lines in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Some times ago I was working with Visual Studio 2017 and if horizontal line of code bigger than VS window, VS was showing it in new line. Look to this picture
[image: VS]

As you see in picture, horizontal lines of Assert takes more then VS window. And sometimes VS moved it in new line and showed green arrow icon under line. But now this formatting is disabled. Does anyone know how to enable this (I'm using c# 2005 keyboard )? I hope i could understand my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go to: 
`Text Editor > All Languages > General` (Or the language you want)
 then you tick the checkbox `Word wrap`(Also `Show visual glyphs for word wrap` if you want to see that arrow you mentioned.).

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple

At first you need to set mouse pointer or cursor in this line end point and then use Alt + Z