# Formatting horizontal lines in Azure Dev

Tags: azure-devops

Visual Studio 2017 has good formatting tool (`Word wrap` and `Show visual glyphs for word wrap`) that shows horizontal lines in new line, if line larger then window.(From [Formatting horizontal lines in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54197389/formatting-horizontal-lines-in-visual-studio-2017) )

[image: VS]

It's a really good thing. And my question is: Does Azure Devops have ability to reformat the code?

[image: Dev azure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Formatting horizontal lines in Azure Dev

When you in the Azure Devops **web code editor**, like edit the file/code in the web code editor, we could right-click in the editor and choose **User Preferences** > **Enable Word Wrap**:

[image]

[image]

But in the Pull Request submission, MS reply that the behavior of **disabling word wrapping is by design**, this makes it better to see the difference in the same line:

[image]

Check [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/187850/word-wrap-setting-not-applying-to-right-editor-in.html) for some more details.

Hope this helps.